# Formatting number as Currency and storing as Integer

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, number-formatting

I have an input field where the user can input a price in the format: `123.456,78 EUR`

```
<p:inputNumber id="amount" symbol=" EUR" ... />
```

In the backing bean the amount must be handled as an integer: `12345678`

```
public String addNewPrice(int amount) {
   // processing and sending to backend
}
```

When I enter: `12,34` (= 12 Euros and 34 Cents) it apparently is recognized as a string, instead of an integer and throws an exception:

> Method not found: class com.proj.ctrl.addNewPrice(java.lang.String)

---

When I add a `numberConverter` it seems to work at first:

```
<p:inputNumber ...>
   <f:convertNumber minFractionDigits = "2" />
</p:inputNumber>
```

It passes the number to the next page, where I'm trying to display it like this:

```
<p:outputLabel id="amount" ...>
   <f:convertNumber minFractionDigits = "2" />
</p:outputLabel>
```

But as an output I get: `1.234,00` instead of `12,34`.

---

**tl;dr:** I'm trying to enter a price formatted as `123.456,78`, store as an integer as `12345678` and display on the next page again formatted as `123.456,78`.

Is this the right approach?

Answer (score 0):

You can save the price in BigDecimal, so in xhtml you would have

```
<p:inputNumber autocomplete="off" id="amount"
        minValue="0" maxValue="999999999999.99" placeholder="0"
        decimalSeparator="," thousandSeparator="."
        decimalPlaces="8" value="#{backingBean.price}">
</p:inputNumber>
```

And the receive the value in your backingBean like:

```
private BigDecimal price; 
// ... Getter & Setter
```

For the output then you can use f:convertNumber

```
<h:outputText style="font-weight: bold;"
        value="#{backingBean.price}">
    <f:convertNumber type="number" pattern="###.###,##"
        locale="de_DE"/>
</h:outputText>
```

Comment: other local and number pattern:
<h:outputText value="#backing.showForView(showedCurrency)">
                        <f:convertNumber type="number" pattern="###,###.########" locale="en_US"/>
</h:outputText>